# VBA: Changing range with each loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use a **VBA** macro to loop through all `.xlsx` files in a folder and copy values from the same range/sheet in each into the file containing the macro.

How do I change the range for `ThisWorkbook` with each loop?

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("I4:AV83").Value = wb.Worksheets(3).Range("A4:AN83").Value
```

The range for the opened file being looped through will always be `A4:AN83`. The range `I4:AV83` is the range for the *first* file to be copied to, the *second* would be `I84:AV163`, the *third* `I164:AV243`, and so on.

The rest of the code is below, and is adapted from [www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com](http://www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com)

```
*original code*
```

**EDIT:** Thank you to those who responded. Since the code was rather long I've removed it and posted an updated version below.

I added in the `.Range(Cells(9, y1), Cells(48, y2))`, and am now having an issue where it will update the values on the wrong range from only one of the loaded sheets.

The first sheet's values should appear on the range `I4:AV83`, but instead only some of the last sheet's values are appearing on the range `I9:AV48`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim y1 As Integer
Dim y2 As Integer

'Set y1 and y2 for value range
  y1 = 4
  y2 = 83

'Optimizes Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'If folder is not selected
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xlsx*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Sets values to the looped file's
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(9, y1), Cells(48, y2)).Value = wb.Worksheets(3).Range("A4:AN83").Value

    'Closes opened Workbook
      wb.Close

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Update range for next loop
      y1 = y1 + 80
      y2 = y2 + 80

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir

  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Complete"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace `wb.Worksheets(3).Range("A4:AN83").Value` with `wb.Worksheets(3).Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(x2, y2)).Value` then you can easily increment x, y, x2, and y2 on each loop.

Comment: Thanks SJR, started to post as a comment then decided to copy and paste to an answer.

Comment: Thank you, though I now seemed to be having a different issue. Updated the original post with the new problem.

Comment: @MTJ I don't quite understand what the issue is now, but a good strategy is to add the code `debug.print y1 & " " y2` just before where you copy and paste. You can then see what the values are by pressing ctrl + g. Alternatively you can set a break point like this [link](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s196/breakpoints.htm)

Comment: The issue seems to be the in the `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(9, y1), Cells(48, y2)).Value = wb.Worksheets(3).Range("A4:AN83").Value`, for whatever reason when the macro finishes it only displays a portion of the values on the range `I9:AV48` even though the `y1` and `y2` values are properly updating (I added the `debug.print y1 & " " y2` and it shows the right values each loop).

Comment: Figured out the answer to my second issue. I messed up the order I for my cells in the `.Range(Cells(9, y1), Cells(48, y2))`, which should have been `.Range(Cells(y1, 9), Cells(y2, 48))`. Other than that everything worked. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MTJ - a warning: `.Range(Cells(y1, 9), Cells(y2, 48))` will crash if the active sheet is not the one that you are obviously using for the `With` block.  You should always qualify which sheet `Range` and `Cells` (and `Rows` and `Columns` and ...) are referring to.  So you should use `.Range(.Cells(y1, 9), .Cells(y2, 48))` - notice the extra periods that I put before the `Cells`.

Comment: @MTJ Or, if this was not in a `With` block (and that was just part of the code) maybe it is meant to be `wb.Worksheets(3).Range(wb.Worksheets(3).Cells(y1, 9), wb.Worksheets(3).Cells(y2, 48))`